# C - Segmentation fault on function with pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a list of 6 elements of a struct type:

```
struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};
```

I'm trying to create a function to initialize these six elements by assigning a random int to each value member.

```
void initializeList(struct entry *l_p)
{
    while(l_p!=_END)
    {
        l_p->value=rand()%999;
        l_p=l_p->next;
    }
}
```

When this function is called in the main, `*l_p` points at the very first element of the list. `_END` is a global constant defined as it follows:

```
struct entry const *_END=(struct entry *)0;
```

Now, every time I run my code I get this:

**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

**Process returned 139 (0x8B)**

I know this means I'm trying to access a part of memory I'm not allowed to, but I can't figure out how to fix my code. Also, I'm pretty sure that the problem is caused by `initializeList` because if I remove it and manually initialize every element of the list, the program runs smoothly.

Comment: Which line of code produces segfault?

Comment: Show more code. Didn't you forget to malloc nodes?

Comment: Your function looks good, provided that each `next` points either to a valid node or to `_END`. (But you sholuld really use the standard `NULL` from `<stdlib.h>`.) I think we need to see the code that sets up the list.

Comment: You probably haven't initialised your list properly. Try stepping through with a debugger or adding printf statements.

Comment: Sorry everybody, my fault. I've been trying to figure it out for so long and now, after a 5 minutes break, I can see that since my list wasn't initialized and the elements weren't linked to each other, I couldn't run a sequential scan over it. Again, my fault, i'm still a noob, got plenty to learn :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry everybody, my fault. I've been trying to figure it out for so long and now, after a 5 minutes break, I can see that since my list wasn't initialized and the elements weren't linked to each other, I couldn't run a sequential scan over it. Again, my fault, i'm still a noob, got plenty to learn :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually there's an error in this:

```
    l_p->value=rand()%999;
    l_p=l_p->next;
```

You haven't allocated memory for l_p & then tried to assign a value in a restricted area leading to a Segmentation fault.

You may try this

```
void initializeList(struct entry *l_p)
{
    l_p=(struct entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    l_p->next=NULL;
    struct entry *pointer,* back=l_p;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        pointer=(struct entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
        pointer->next=NULL;
        back->next=pointer;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        l_p->value=rand()%999;
        l_p=l_p->next;
    }
}
```

I've created 6 nodes and connected them in the first 9 lines.

Then assigned values to each of them in the next lines.

Comment: The question can't be answered since we don't know how memory is allocated or how the structs are initialized.

Comment: No, it was a simple function that iterates through an existing list. There is no need to change it to create a list. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Then there might be an error while creating the list

Comment: No need to cast `malloc()`'s result in C.